# How to detect the end of input in conduit?

Tags: haskell, eof, conduit

I'm trying to use [network-conduit](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/network-conduit/1.0.0/doc/html/Data-Conduit-Network.html) as a backend for (patched) HaskellNet's [IMAP](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.3.1/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-IMAP.html). One of the [required operations](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/HaskellNet/0.3.1/doc/html/Network-HaskellNet-BSStream.html) is to detect if the stream is open. Currently I'm using

```
isOpen :: (Monad m) => ConduitM i o m Bool
isOpen = await >>= maybe (return False) ((True <$) . leftover)
```

Is this correct, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct, the only possible improvement is you could use the `peek` helper function, but what you have here is fine.